# JQUERY AJAX gives URL parameter error 404

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

WHEN the json file new.php used by more then one user the Jquery Ajax function returns to the onfailure:
and consol having:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

is this error because of server? currently i am on shared hosting.

```
var session_id = /SESS\w*ID=([^;]+)/i.test(document.cookie) ? RegExp.$1 : false;
var url = window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.hostname+'/folder/new.php?a='+session_id;
new Ajax.Request(url, {
method: 'get',
dataType: 'json',
cache:false,
onCreate: function() {

},
onSuccess: function(transport) {
.....
}
onFailure:  function() {
            currencyFetchStatus = { status:'<strong>Disconnected! failed to Connect!</strong>', style:{ color:'red'} };
            connected = false;
        }
```

Comment: Why would you expect to get something else? Does the file exist?

Comment: Is `new.php` designed to throw a 404 error on a specific condition?

Comment: yes file definitely exist

Comment: new.php is jason encoded file

Comment: Have you outputted `window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.hostname...` to console and tried the URL in the browser?

Comment: Yes, of course when multiple user logged from different computers then the error 404 occurs. i remind one thing that wordpress is intall at my hosting server. because of this?